# How To Add Two Store Tags

Tags: expresso-store, tags, ee

If I need to add two store tags together to make up a sum, how would I go about this? This is what I want to achieve:

{order_discount} + {order_you_save} = R total savings

Is this possible? I still obviously need the total savings to reflect on the total amount of the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into Store that I know of that would allow you to do this. You could however use something like [MX Calculator](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-calculator) or a similar add-on to calculate the total.

Something along the lines of:

```
{exp:mx_calc expression="{order_discount_val} + {order_you_save_value}" parse="inward"}
 Total Savings of {calc_result}
{/exp:mx_calc}
```

Notice that I added `_val` to each of the tags so that they will be outputted without the currency symbols, you will need to do this or the math will not work correctly.